# DynamoDB indexing and audit log

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I want to store a mapping in a DynamoDB datbase, this mapping is between an account and a list of thing that account have access too. (This is a stand alone system and do not handle authentication, so my document would only contain this information)

Example:

```
Kasper, have access to Room301 and Room302.
Peter, have access to Room301 and Room303.
```

Example

```
{
 account: "Kasper",
 rooms: ["Room301", "Room302"]
}
```

But i also want to store an audit log of changes done.
Example `"Admin123 added Room302 to Kasper"`

My idea would be to store this in the same document, as you would always only want this information in connection to "Kasper".

An Example:

```
{
 account: "Kasper",
 rooms: ["Room301", "Room302"]
 audit: [
  { 
    user: "Admin123",
    log: "Admin123 added Room302"
  }
  { 
    user: "Admin123",
    log: "Admin123 created account Kasper"
  }
 ]
}
```

However we are discussing adding the audit log to the document would fragment the database and make lookups slower. Is this correct?

Once in a while would we need to do a search for account that have access to a given room, example all account with access to Room301. Are there a way DynamoDB can index this or would this require me to use a RDS solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DynamoDB doesn't support creating index on complex data types like `List` or `Set`. In the above model, the `rooms` attribute could have been defined as `List` or `Set`. So, index cannot be defined on `rooms` attribute.

If you can change the data model as mentioned below, you can define **GSI** on `room` attribute and use **Query API** to get the accounts based on `room` attribute.

> account - Partition Key
>
> room - Sort Key  -  define GSI with room attribute as partition key
>
> audit - non-key attribute

```
{
 account: "Kasper",
 rooms: "Room301",
 audit: [
  { 
    user: "Admin123",
    log: "Admin123 added Room301"
  }
 ]
},
{
 account: "Kasper",
 rooms: "Room302",
 audit: [
  { 
    user: "Admin234",
    log: "Admin234 created account Kasper for room Room302"
  }
 ]
}
```